# Is being finitely generated module a local property?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

There is this result on stack project, saying that let $S$ be a $R$-module and $f_1,...,f_n \in R$ that generates $R$, if $S_{f_i}$ is finitely generated $R_{f_i}$-module then $S$ is a finitely generated $R$ module.

https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00EN#comment-6672

I am asking if this is true:

if $S$ is a $R$-module and $f_1,...,f_n \in R$ generates $R$, and if $S_{f_i}$ is finitely generated **$R$-module** then $S$ is a finitely generated $R$ module.

---

Thanks for the comments! I am now clear on this.

To complete what is written on stack project,

1. $S$ be a $R$-module and $f_1,...,f_n \in R$ that generates $R$, if $S_{f_i}$ is finitely generated $R_{f_i}$-module then $S$ is a finitely generated $R$ module. (This is true on stack project.)
2. $S$ be a $R$-module and $f_1,...,f_n \in R$ that generates $R$, if $S_{f_i}$ is finitely generated $R$-module then $S$ is a finitely generated $R$ module. (This follows from 1.)
3. $S$ be a $R$-algebra and $f_1,...,f_n \in R$ that generates $R$, if $S_{f_i}$ is finitely generated $R_{f_i}$-algebra then $S$ is a finitely generated $R$ module. (This is wrong: take $R=S=\mathbb{Z}, f_1=2, f_2=3$ as indicated by Wilberd.)
4. $S$ be a $R$-algebra and $f_1,...,f_n \in R$ that generates $R$, if $S_{f_i}$ is finitely generated $R_{f_i}$-algebra then $S$ is a finitely generated $R$ module. (This is true, on stack project.)

Comment: If $S_{f_i}$ is a finitely generated $R$-mdoule isn't it automatically a finitely generated $R$-modules? Should some of the "module"s be "algebra" here?

Comment: The condition is not weaker, but stronger. There are more scalars in $R_f$ than in $R$.

Comment: Try the following example: $R=S=\mathbb Z$, $f_1=2$, $f_2=3$.

Comment: Thank you! I got a bit confused. So by stack project, both as R-mod and $R_{f_i}$-mod will work!